# Jetty Large file upload OutOfMemoryError

Tags: apache-camel, jetty

What is the correct way to upload a large file in streaming mode (using multipart/form-data), i mean start processing file immediately without waiting for the entire file upload into memory using camel-jetty component

I get `java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`

Here the camel route

```java
public class InputHttpRoute extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        from(http())
                .noStreamCaching()
                .process(e -> {
                    e.getIn(AttachmentMessage.class).getAttachments()
                            .forEach((s, dataHandler) -> {
                                InputStream files = null;
                                try {
                                    files = dataHandler.getInputStream();
                                    byte[] buffer = new byte[10500];
                                    int b;
                                    while ((b = files.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                                        // Convert byte to character
                                        String data = new String(buffer, 0, b);
                                        System.err.println(data);
                                    }
                                } catch (IOException ex) {
                                    throw new RuntimeException(ex);
                                }
                            });

                });
        //  .setBody(constant("xxx"))
        ;
    }

    private static String http() {
        return new StringBuilder("jetty:http://0.0.0.0:8787/email/myservice")
                .append("?httpMethodRestrict=")
                .append("POST")
                .append("&disableStreamCache=true")
                .append("&eagerCheckContentAvailable=true")
                .append("&exchangePattern=InOnly")
                .append("&chunked=true")
                .append("&requestBufferSize=0")
                .append("&responseBufferSize=0")

                /*      .append("&requestBufferSize=")
                      .append(100)
                      .append("&requestHeaderSize=")
                      .append(100)
                      .append("&disableStreamCache=true")*/
                .toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the whole stacktrace for when you get the `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` ?

Comment: This behavior is not configurable on Apache Camel (yet) - https://github.com/apache/camel/pull/12240